# How do i use whereRelation on a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a "Person" model that can morph to to different types, in my example im searching for Persons that are a Partner.

But i only want to find Persons that are Partners of a specific category, so i try and use "whereRelation".

```
$this->contacts = Person::where('model_type', Partner::class)
    ->when($this->selected_category, function ($query) {
        $query->whereRelation('model', 'category_id', $this->selected_category);
    })
    ->get();
```

But since the database contains Persons that are of other types than Partner, and those other types do not have a "category_id" column, then Laravel throws an error: Column not found! Even though im limiting my search to only look for Persons that have that column.

I have searched for answers, and i have asked Chat GPT and tried all responses i got, but none have been successful.

Comment: It sounds like you're answering your own question: *'and those other types do not have a "category_id" column'*

Comment: I'm aware of that, but since i never try to actually search or access those columns im hoping there is an easy way around the problem!